# How to model many-to-many relationships with a relationship entity in EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Popular example: In the issue tracker JIRA, issues can be linked to other issues. The link itself has some data attached, in particular a type.

Example:

**Issue A** -> *depends on* -> **Issue B**
**Issue B** <- *is depended on by* <- **Issue A**

We are introducing the same kind of relationship for an entity in our C# ASP.NET MVC application using EF 4.1 CodeFirst, and I'm wondering **how to best model this relationship?**

---

**Details**:

There are some particularities about this situation:

- A link has some data attached, so we can't simply model a many-to-many relationship between issues and issues. We rather have to introduce a new entity **Link**, which represents a relationship between two issues.
- A link, by definition, links *two* instances of the same entity, it is a "two-to-many" relationship (a link has two issues, an issue can have many links).
- The link is directed, which means, if Issue A *depends on* Issue B, then Issue B *is depended on by* Issue A.

We will certainly have a **Link** entity that looks like this:

```
public class Link
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Issue IssueA { get; set; }
    public Issue IssueB { get; set; }
    public LinkType Type { get; set; }
}
```

The Issue class might look like this:

```
public class Issue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

Currently there would be only one link type: dependency. So, the link type would look like this:

```
public class LinkType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ForwardName { get; set; } // depends on
    public string BackwardName { get; set; } // is depended on by
}
```

**Now for the big question:**

If I want EF to automatically manage `Issue.Links`, I have to tell it what Foreign key on the `Link` table to use. Either I use `IssueA`, or I use `IssueB`. I can't use both, can I?

Either I define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasMany(i => i.Links).WithRequired(l => l.IssueA);
```

or I define:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasMany(i => i.Links).WithRequired(l => l.IssueB);
```

---

**Possible approaches** - I am curious about your feedback on whether some of them will lead to troubles, cannot be implemented, or whether any of these approaches can be regarded as "best practice":

- Add two Collections to the **Issue**, `ICollection<Link> OutgoingLinks`, `ICollection<Link> IncomingLinks`. This way the collections can be maintained by EF, but from a business logic point of view they don't make much sense.
- Only add one collection and configure EF 4.1 to add incoming *and* outgoing links to it, if that is possible.
- Only add one collection and implement it on my own:

  `ICollection<Link> AllLinks { return _context.Links.Where(l => l.IssueA == this || l.IssueB == this).ToList(); }`

  The problem with this approach is that the domain entity executes data access tasks which is bad in terms of seperation of concerns.
- Any other?

Comment: Only first solution is correct and only that solution will work with EF. It is also correct from business perspective because you mention that link is directed so it is a big difference if issue is dependent on another issue or another issue is dependent on this issue.

Comment: @Ladislav: Thanks. I knew I can count on you to answer :-) - Concerning business perspective: Using the properties of the link object the direction information could still be retrieved, but I would always want to get a list of *all* links of an Issue, never only the incoming or outgoing set (I reckon...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option (1) is the way to go in my opinion, together with a readonly helper perhaps which combines the two collections:

```
public class Issue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> OutgoingLinks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> InComingLinks { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Link> Links // not mapped because readonly
    {
        get { return OutgoingLinks.Concat(InComingLinks); }
    }
}
```

Option (2) isn't possible because you cannot map one navigation property to two different ends/navigation properties.

Comment: Hi Slauma. Thanks for the response. The readonly property is a good hint for a helpful extension to support the business perspective.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing :-)